# Asymptotic expansion for calculating exact value

Tags: numerical-methods, asymptotics

I have shown that $F(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}{(1+xt)^2}dt\sim\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (n+1)! x^n$ as $x\rightarrow 0_+$.

My question now is that when we are given a small value $x$ how can I find the value of $n$ in terms of smallest magnitude? For example what is the exact value of $F(0.1)$ by optimal truncation?

Comment: What is Lagrange remainder ? This gives you one equation in $x$. Is solving that your problem ?

Comment: Is it not simpler to obtain the integral in closed form and then investigate the small  x behaviour?

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  Are you trying to find the value of $n$ for which $(n+1)!x^n$ is smallest?  Also, what is $F$?

Comment: Yes you are right, I edited $F$ in the start post, it denotes the integral

Comment: Using some rough estimates it's possible to show that the optimal $n$ is asymptotic to $1/x$ as $x \to 0^+$.  Is this about what you're looking for, or are you seeking more accuracy?

Comment: Are you sure its asymptotic to $1/x$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ because an approximation for $F(0.1)=0.843666...$

Comment: Numerically it's correct to two digits when $x = 0.1$: $\sum_{n=0}^{1/x} (-1)^n (n+1)! x^n = 0.8457\ 9968$.  When $x = 0.05$ it's correct to five digits, and when $x = 0.025$ it's correct to fourteen digits.

Comment: Yes but how can I find the value/s of n?

Comment: I just remembered there's a straightforward way to calculate $n$.  I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(n) = (n+1)! x^n$ is convex, so the value of $n$ which minimizes $f(n)$ is the smallest $n$ for which

$$
f(n) \leq f(n+1).
$$

That is,

$$
(n+1)!x^n \leq (n+2)! x^{n+1},
$$

or, after dividing through by the left-hand side,

$$
1 \leq (n+2)x.
$$

Thus

$$
n \geq \frac{1}{x} - 2.
$$

The smallest integer $n$ satisfying this inequality is

$$
n = \left\lceil \frac{1}{x} - 2 \right\rceil.
$$